# VK API БОТ отправка сообщений

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, tomcat

Делаю бота vk с помощью Java SDK.

Для теста сделал так:

Я пишу ему сообщение, а он мне отправляет его содержимое обратно.

Вроде все и работает, но проблема в том, что он отправляет через несколько минут его снова и так пару раз. Посмотрел в запросах группы и там действительно есть запросы message_new, которые я вроде не слал... Может нужно после того как бот отработал событие отправить флаг о его успешном завершении, чтоб он заново его не отрабатывал?

Comment: все может быть...

Comment: @michael_best и зачем это вообще писать?